# Проблема с кнопкой, ссылка на весь блок

Tags: html, css

Как сделать чтобы кнопка "Play" не имела ссылку во всю ширину, перепробовал все варианты display, ничего не помогло.

```css
.fa-play {
  color: #000;
  display: table;
  font-size: 28px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 32.5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1.5px solid #000;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition: 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="#modalvideo" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61650/discussion-on-question-by-user234223-------).